# ETPush IllegalFormatConversionException when location not available

Tags: android, salesforce-sdk-android

I am using the Android ExactTarget push SDK version 4.1.0 pulled through my gradle file.  Whenever I try running the app when the user is only using GPS for location (not mobile networks), the app crashes.

I get this error in the log:

```
java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: %d can't format java.lang.String arguments
at java.util.Formatter.badArgumentType(Formatter.java:1489)
at java.util.Formatter.transformFromInteger(Formatter.java:1689)
at java.util.Formatter.transform(Formatter.java:1461)
at java.util.Formatter.doFormat(Formatter.java:1081)
at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:1042)
at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:1011)
at java.lang.String.format(String.java:1803)
at com.exacttarget.etpushsdk.i.a(SourceFile:1351)
at com.exacttarget.etpushsdk.i.onResult(SourceFile:1322)
at com.google.android.gms.common.api.zzb$zza.zzb(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.common.api.zzb$zza.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5835)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

Here is my readyAimFire method:

```
ETPush.readyAimFire(new ETPushConfig.Builder(this)
.setEtAppId(getString(R.string.exact_target_app_id))
.setAccessToken(getString(R.string.exact_target_access_token))
.setGcmSenderId(getString(R.string.gcm_sender_id))
.setAnalyticsEnabled(true)
.setPiAnalyticsEnabled(true)
.setLocationEnabled(true)
.setLogLevel(debug ? Log.DEBUG : Log.ERROR)
.build()
);
```

It looks like the only thing going wrong is when it tries formatting a log message, it crashes.  However, even changing the log level does not solve the problem.  Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Thank you Alex.  We are aware of the issue and a fix is forthcoming.

Comment: @BillMote Is there a temporary work around for now?  Is there an estimate on how long until a fix will be available?

Comment: We are testing a Hotfix and it should be available shortly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Alex.  This item has been resolved in hotfix release v4.1.1 and is available for immediate consumption.